# Chrome-less Window in uwp

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml, xamarin.uwp, windows-community-toolkit

I have a scenario where I have to create a chromeless window.
This type of window we can easily create in WPF By just setting Window Style to None.So now if I have only one shape on a page then the only shape will be visible not all title border etc.

Do anyone have an idea how to achieve a similar type of effect in UWP?.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a scenario where I have to create a chromeless window.

As you know, UWP doesn’t support chromeless, non-rectangular windows, but this can be accomplished by adding a desktop extension to your UWP app package that uses a WPF Window to provide the required chromeless window. And Stefan Wick has a blog to explain this detailly. You could google **Creating chromeless, non-rectangular Windows from UWP** for the detail steps, hope these can help you.

Comment: Hi Nico thanks for guiding me,I have gone through Stefan Wick blog, added the WPF window as a desktop extension,  In My case once I will try to open the WPF window from uwp and vice versa taking time to switch. And if the user installed any antivirus it is taking more time.

Comment: I run Stefan Wick app in my side, it looks well for opening wpf window, and as you know, we need to launch wpf app and make new window, this does take some  time.  *And if the user installed any antivirus it is taking more time* I have not environment for testing, so we could not make sure antivirus will cause this.